# JUnit test which use void

Tags: java, junit

I have a class `Person` and which has a void method `showDataPerson()` which prints:

```
JavaSeller SA (nip: 567854367)
Address 1
12-345 Warsaw
Numer konta:
23456789765456789098765456
```

How can I make correct test?

Class

```
public void showDataPerson() {
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
    if (!company.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(company + " " + "(nip: " + nip + ")");
    }
    System.out.println(address);
    System.out.println(addressContinued);
    if (!accountNumber.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Numer konta:");
        System.out.println(accountNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
```

Test

```
@Test
public void testAddPerson() {
    Person test = new Person("Bill", "Cage", "JavaSeller SA", "567854367", "Address 1", "12-345 Warsaw", "23456789765456789098765456");
    test.showDataPerson();
    assertEquals("Bill Cage\n" +
            "JavaSeller SA (nip: 567854367)\n" +
            "Address 1\n" +
            "12-345 Warsaw\n" +
            "Numer konta:\n" +
            "23456789765456789098765456", test.showDataPerson());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that you can implement is to have two methods one that returns as a string the representation of the data to be shown:

```
public String dataPersonToString() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append("\n");
    str.append(firstName + " " + lastName);
    if (!company.isEmpty()) {
         str.append(company + " " + "(nip: " + nip + ")");
    }
    str.append((address);
    str.append((addressContinued);
    if (!accountNumber.isEmpty()) {
       str.append(("Numer konta:");
       str.append((accountNumber);
    }
    str.append(("\n");
    return str;
}
```

and the showDataPerson to only print the data:

```
public void showDataPerson() {
    System.out.println(dataPersonToString());
}
```

change your Test to test what really matter, the `dataPersonToString` method:

```
@Test
public void testAddPerson() {
    Person test = new Person("Bill", "Cage", "JavaSeller SA", "567854367", "Address 1", "12-345 Warsaw", "23456789765456789098765456");
    test.showDataPerson();
    assertEquals("Bill Cage\n" +
            "JavaSeller SA (nip: 567854367)\n" +
            "Address 1\n" +
            "12-345 Warsaw\n" +
            "Numer konta:\n" +
            "23456789765456789098765456", test.dataPersonToString());
}
```

The advantages of this approach IMO is: 1) separation of concerns, *i.e.,*  you are separating the string represent of the data from the printing of the data. 2) It is clean, readable, and straightforward to implement, neither do you need to perform big refactoring on the original code nor in the test code.